# Ajax Contact form validation and submit

Tags: ajax, contact-form

I'm trying to make a HTML contact form. Here's my code
`Get in Touch

```
                    <p class="success-sending-message">Thank you, your message has been sent!</p>
                    <p class="error-sending-message">There has been an error, please try again.</p>

                    <div id="contact-form">

                        <form action="" id="contactForm" class="styled" method="post">

                            <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" tabindex="3" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" value="" class="requiredField textbox" />

                            <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" tabindex="4" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" value="" class="requiredField email textbox" />

                            <label for="contact_subject">Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" tabindex="5" id="contact_subject" name="contact_subject" value="" class="requiredField textbox" />

                            <label for="contact_message">Your Message</label>
                            <div class="textarea-wrap">
                                <textarea cols="65" rows="9" tabindex="6" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" class="requiredField"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-section">
                                <button class="button" tabindex="7" type="submit" id="born-submit" name="born-submit">Send Message</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                                <span class="sending-message"><img src="css/images/loading-light.gif" /> Sending...</span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>`
```

And here's my validation script

```
$(window).load(function() {

/* Ajax Contact form validation and submit */
jQuery('form#contactForm').submit(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.error').remove();
    var hasError = false;
    jQuery(this).find('.requiredField').each(function() {
        if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()) == '') {
            if (jQuery(this).is('textarea')){
                jQuery(this).parent().addClass('input-error');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).addClass('input-error');
            }
            hasError = true;
        } else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('email')) {
            var emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
            if(!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()))) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('input-error');
                hasError = true;
            }
        }
    });
    if(!hasError) {
        jQuery(this).find('#born-submit').fadeOut('normal', function() {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.sending-message').show('normal');
        });
        var formInput = jQuery(this).serialize();
        var contactForm = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
            data: formInput,
            success: function(data){
                contactForm.parent().fadeOut("normal", function() {
                    jQuery(this).prev().prev().show('normal'); // Show success message
                });
            },
            error: function(data){
                contactForm.parent().fadeOut("normal", function() {
                    jQuery(this).prev().show('normal');  // Show error message
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return false;

});

jQuery('.requiredField').blur(function() {
    if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()) != '' && !jQuery(this).hasClass('email')) {
        if (jQuery(this).is('textarea')){
            jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('input-error');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    } else {
        if (jQuery(this).is('textarea')){
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('input-error');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).addClass('input-error');
        }
    }
});

jQuery('.email').blur(function() {
    emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if(emailReg.test(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val())) && jQuery(this).val() != '') {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('input-error');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).addClass('input-error');
    } 
});

jQuery('.requiredField, .email').focus(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).is('textarea')){
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('input-error');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('input-error');
    }
});

});
```

My form is working properly, After filling details It is showing me "Thank you, your message has been sent!" But where is this message going, I don't have any of the process.php file and all.  I want that email should be send to my email id.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour ... Look in the firebug or chrome developper tools console to see the post trace.
In your php file, you can put echos or var_dump to be sure all it's ok.

Another thing ... the form action is empty.

Comment: I tried to see with firebug, but unable to find the any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no where it is going. Give where it needs to go in the `action=""` attribute of the `<form>`. And also, in the actioned URL, typically, a PHP file, give this code:

```
<?php
    if (count($_POST))
    {
        $name = $_POST["contact_name"];
        $email = $_POST["contact_email"];
        $subject = $_POST["contact_subject"];
        $message = $_POST["contact_message"];
        $mail = "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nSubject: $subject\nMessage: $message";
        if (mail("mymail@domain.com", "New Mail from Contact Form", $mail))
            die ("OK");
        else
            die ("Fail");
    }
?>
```

Also, you need to make a small correction in your JavaScript AJAX Call. Replace this way:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
        data: formInput,
        success: function(data){
            if (data == "OK")
                contactForm.parent().fadeOut("normal", function() {
                    jQuery(this).prev().prev().show('normal'); // Show success message
                });
            else
                alert ("Message not sent!");
        },
        error: function(data){
            contactForm.parent().fadeOut("normal", function() {
                jQuery(this).prev().show('normal');  // Show error message
            });
        }
    });
```

#### Test if your server supports SMTP through PHP Script

Create a small file, which has this content, say `mail.php`:

```
<?php
    var_dump(mail("yourmail@gmail.com", "Testing Message", "This mail was sent from PHP Script."));
?>
```

And try to access the file and see what you are getting. Please update the same in your question.

Comment: @user1730704 there were issues with the JavaScript too. Have updated the same in the answer.

Comment: I change mymail@domain.com with my gmail id, and also correct the above code in my script. But when I submit my details, It said Message not send! (In a pop up).

Comment: So, your SMTP Server is not configured properly. Get in touch with your hosting provider and check if they allow sending mails through scripts.

Comment: @user1730704 Please see the updated answer. Test if your server supports SMTP through PHP Script. 
Create a small file, which has this content, say `mail.php`: `<?php
        var_dump(mail("yourmail@gmail.com", "Testing Message", "This mail was sent from PHP Script."));
    ?>`. Let us know the result. Please update the same in your question.

And try to access the file and see what you are getting. Please update the same in your question.

Comment: I tried with other script, It was working fine. I received an email. I tried to upload this thing http://css-tricks.com/nice-and-simple-contact-form/ and it was working fine.

Comment: You gave that `/* Modification by Toni for Windows servers */
ini_set("sendmail_from", "me@mydomain.co.uk");` in your code? If so, just revert back to your code and just insert this code and check out. Is your server, a Windows server?

Comment: And what was the result of the script which I asked you to check?

Comment: I'm uploading my edited files to different server please look at this url http://skyprojects.site50.net/gym/contact.html you can check error message by yourself. I'm also upload other script but it is working fine http://skyprojects.site50.net/Contact/

Comment: @ Praveen And by the way I tried your script as well mail.php, When i access the file it said "bool(true)"

Comment: @user1730704 Your script **WILL NOT** work, whatsoever, because the hosting server puts an ad like `<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->`